# EF: updating a sql view or adding custom properties

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, view

i'm starting out with EF, and need some basic guidelines

i have a table named Persons with firstname,lastname,birthdate and more

now i bind a datagrid to it (in WPF) and alls fine

but how do i create a column for Fullname (lastname, firstname)?

in my past projects (ms access, asp.net) i would make a view name viwpersons and have all the calculated/computed columns there. and then bind the UI to the view

with EF, if you bind a view then there are a few issues

1. you must always again and again remove the `definingquery`, otherwise you cant update
2. when a user edits the lastname or firstame, the field is not updated till the whole datagrid is rebound or refreshed
3. inserts and deletes are totally impossible
4. even if the editing datagrid is connected to the table, so we can insert and delete, the changes are not reflected in dropdownlists etc. around the app, as they are connected to an `ObservableCollection` of the view, not the table

so after a few weeks hacking this way and that, i decided to go "conceptual" or "logical" or whatever. i deleted the view from my edmx and am going to work only with the tables. i'm trying to add my first calculated column to the table. as per many blogs i added this to my code

```
Partial Class Person
    <System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember()> ReadOnly Property FullName
    Get
        Return LastName & ", " & FirstName
    End Get
End Property
End Class
```

but this approach also has some problems

1. trying to filter on this, gives me an error `Late binding operations cannot be converted to an expression tree.` [now i believe that's true, as there's no way that mssql can filter on this field that does not exist there]
2. no other application or service can use the db directly, as it dont have no views, IF all logic will be put in the EF code
3. performance, putting fields in code disables all the "set-based" power of mssql for summing and joining millions of records (in above sample its irrelevant, but eventually i have much more fields that id need, such as balances)

so what is the right, preferred, "EF-way" of doing this?

all the best, and i appreciate your advice

Comment: anybody has any ideas? i really need a good answer here. thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the example given, would calculating the field in the database meet your needs?

`alter table person add fullname as lastname + ', ' + firstname` (sql server)

Comment: for this simple requirement yes. but my question is broader. i.e. the persons balance which is calculated via a `union query`, then joined to the Persons table via `inner join`. i want to show this column in the datagrid showing the persons, but the problems abound...